# tikz make node as large as its neighbor

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the blue node scale automatically depending on the red nodes size?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox{\linetmp}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.multipart,positioning,shapes}

\NewDocumentCommand{\threepart}{mmmm}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=60pt,fill=red] (date) {#1};
    \node[right= 0pt of date.east,fill=cyan] (title) {\bfseries#2};
    \node[below= 0pt of date.south west,anchor=north west] (body) {#3};
    \node[below= 0pt of body] (quote) {\textit#4};
    \draw[thick]  (date.south west) -- (title.south east);
    \node[inner sep=0pt,draw,thick,rounded corners,fit=(date)(title)(body)(quote)] (W) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\threepart{Services}{Event Driven Framework}{OS Adapter Layer}{4}

\bigskip

\noindent
\threepart{Some very long text in the left field}{Some very long text in the upper right field}{Some very long text in the lower  field}{4}

\end{document}
```

https://www.latex4technics.com?note=zzvqsg
[image]